# getting a string c++

Tags: c++, string, getline

I have a problem getting a string.
I use

```
getline(cin,string);
```

but there is some kind of a bug and it skips a row when I press enter, is there a solution to this problem, or maybe another function to get a string with empty spaces?

Comment: Show the entire code, and what exactly you input, and what you expected

Comment: what you mean as skips a row? skips a line where you did oress enter or a next line?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you are doing `cin >> someVar` somewhere before you do the `getline()`.

`cin >> someVar`
Doesn't read a complete line, but stops on the first whitespace character, and the newline `\n` remains unconsumed., which then causes the skipping of line in `getline()`

If this is the case,

To fix it, you need to add a `cin.ignore()` statement before the `getline()` to consume the `\n` newline character (or any other extra characters) left in the input stream by the `>>` stream extractor.